# Why can't I have template and default arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, default-parameters

I changed a paremeter in a function to accept any kind of object using a template but I can't use it in conjunction with other default parameters, is there something I am missing?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
    public:
    std::wstring msg = L"hey";
    MyClass(){};
};

class MyClass2{
    public:
    template<class T> MyClass2(T* t, int i);
};
template<class T>
MyClass2::MyClass2(T* t,int i=0){ std::wcout << t->msg << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyClass mc;
    MyClass2 mc2(&mc);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
practice.cpp:16:32: error: redeclaration of 'MyClass2::MyClass2(T*, int)' may not have default arguments [-fpermissive]
```

I thought it was reasonable to not use default values in the template but is there a reason for the other parameters?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**You certainly [can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59f6e9d472b06296); put the default argument on the declaration, not the definition.**

Putting the default in the definition's argument list instead of the declaration's is an added extra that is not available for function templates:

> `[C++14: 8.3.6/4]:` For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later declarations of a function in the same scope. *[..]*

I don't really know why this restriction is in place.

Similar rule:

> `[C++14: 8.3.6/6]:` Except for member functions of class templates, the default arguments in a member function definition that appears outside of the class definition are added to the set of default arguments provided by the member function declaration in the class definition *[..]*